# He's bound to be suspicious

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

Why phrase 'He's bound to be suspicious' can be translated by two opposite meanings?

1. He simply has to be suspicious. (look like a suspicious character)
2. He will probably suspect something.

Comment: I would dispute that those are 'opposite' meanings. One of Oxford Dictionaries' definitions of _bound_ is _destined or very likely to have a specified experience_.

Comment: For me, it's the opposite things - looking suspicious or suspecting something.

Comment: Oh, you mean _be suspicious_ in the sense of _look like a suspicious character_?  I don't think we would ever use _to be suspicious_ with that meaning, precisely because it is ambiguous.

Comment: Yes I mean this - look like a suspicious character. So the  meanings are realy ambiguous for non-native speaker.. How do you express these 2 different meanings in English?

Comment: For meaning 1 you could say "he's bound to look suspicious". But even with your original wording, it's possible that the ambiguity would be resolved by context.

Comment: I don't consider those meanings to be opposite. I think the opposite of looking suspicious is looking trustworthy; the opposite of feeling suspicious about something is feeling trusting, or confident of the truth of something.

Comment: You could disambiguate by saying "He's bound to suspect something." and "He's bound to be suspected."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He's bound to be suspicious.

This sentence is ambiguous in that (1) others may suspect him, or (2) he may suspect others.

Therefore, the sentence gives two opposite meanings, as you've mentioned.

For the 1st meaning, you can say :

> He's bound to look suspicious.

For the 2nd meaning, you can say :

> He's bound to be suspicious of something/someone.